# How do you use a UIPickerView to determine the value of a UITextField?

Tags: swift, uikit, uipickerview

I've built a UIPickerView that lets the user pick from all of the states in the US. My goal is for the user to tap on the UITextField and for the UIPickerView to pop up with the options. How do I join the UITextField and the UIPickerView?

Thanks!

Comment: Scan [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+uitextfield+uipickerview+inputview) for lots of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // define variables 
    var timeSlotsPickerView = UIPickerView()
    @IBOutlet weak var timeSlotTextField: BasicTextField!


     override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            timeSlotsPickerView.delegate = self
            timeSlotTextField.inputView = timeSlotsPickerView // textfield inputview will open pickerview
        }

use the delegate and datasource methods of pickerview

 func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return array[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        timeSlotTextField.text = "\(array[row])"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do exactly the same thing for a project, so I created a custom control to do this.

You can get the code on github https://github.com/CarterMiller/TextFieldExtensions and either use it as-is, or as the starting point for your own version

You can extend UITextField, and set everything up in 'becomeFirstResponder'

In my example, I present the UITableView in a popup view, but you could equally have it displayed somewhere in the same ViewController

Comment: Thanks Russell. Not exactly what I'm looking for but I like the idea of the library. Nice work